# NodeJS Bug? Error when a return statement with a line feed before the string to be returned is executed

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, return, newline

I'm trying call a function, from a module, to build a HTML string.
When the function is written in the below way, with a LF(Line Feed) between the return statement and the string declaration, the return is "undefined"...

```
exports.buildHtmlContent = function (content) {
    return
    "<!DOCTYPE html>                    \
    \n<html lang='en-US'>               \
    \n  <head>                          \
    \n  </head>                         \
    \n  <body>                          \
    \n      <h1>" + content + "</h1>    \
    \n  </body>                         \
    \n</html>";
};
```

However, when the function is written in this other below way, without the LF after return statement, it works properly!

```
exports.buildHtmlContent = function (content) {
    return "<!DOCTYPE html>             \
    \n<html lang='en-US'>               \
    \n  <head>                          \
    \n  </head>                         \
    \n  <body>                          \
    \n      <h1>" + content + "</h1>    \
    \n  </body>                         \
    \n</html>";
};
```

This is a bug in NodeJs?
The NodeJs interpretation from the function 1 looks like it thinks the return is empty, even with the miss of ";", and didn't correlate the below string declaration with the return statement.
Apparently NodeJs didn't check the miss of ";" before decide that is the interpretation end of the "return" statement.

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with JavaScript, and not Node.js specifically. Most JavaScript engines implement [Automatic Semi-colon Insertion](http://jamesallardice.com/understanding-automatic-semi-colon-insertion-in-javascript/), meaning that it will try to automatically separate two clauses with a semi-colon. The statement `return` on its own is valid, as it will return `undefined`, and a string is a valid statement as well. For example:

```
"use strict";
```

The reason why ASI is triggered is due to both the line break, and `return` being a *restricted production*. Not a bug, but a feature.

Comment: Note: It's due to `return` statements being [restricted productions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) -- the few statements in JavaScript that limit the use of line-breaks. Other than these, ASI isn't so aggressive as to insert a semicolon with every line-break.